# Since macros are gone, how can I easily add a new Guid?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have a project that requires me to add 100's of guid's to control definitions.

VS obviously does come with a guid generator, but it's still a chore to format the code:

```
new Guid("{4FF4E137-2B94-40A9-9CD7-9FB985A35AB0}")
```

Besides actually creating a plugin for this to insert a new guid declaration at current selection, is there an easier way to do this?

This was possible with a macro, Macros got removed a while ago though.

Comment: You could write an add-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this plugin which does exactly what I want:

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/270f94f9-4631-4d95-8407-7954acd11bd7